# IOS: UILongPressGestureRecognizer EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have this code in viewDidLoad:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *change = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChange:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:change];
    for (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in imageView.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:change];
    }
```

when I call the class where is this code, the first time it's all ok , but the second time it crash because EXC_BAD_ACCESS; it don't happens if instead of an imageView I use a scrollView, why???

Comment: without seeing some more of your code, I can't help you... try turning on NSZombiesEnabled or profiling for Zombies.

Comment: -[CFSet countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14ab30 (this is the message)

Comment: Are you manually releasing your view's gesture recognizers? You are not supposed to do that.

Comment: because when I started my project I set "use automatic reference counting"

Answer (score 2):

With this code, you are requiring all recognizers (including change) to fail for change to succeed, which cannot be good

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *change = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChange:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:change];
for (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in imageView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:change];
}
```

you should change it to this

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *change = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragGestureChange:)];
for (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in imageView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:change];
}
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:change];
```

And you should release change here. Don't know if that will actually solve your problem, can't see anything else wrong in what you posted.

Comment: I can't release "change" because in my project I choosed "use autometic reference counting"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this: [UIButtonLongTab](http://www.isignmeout.com/adding-long-tap-functionality-uibutton/). Use the Background-Image for your Images. I use this in an App within a ScrollView and it works without problem.